# Delete duplicates array issue

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code from this website but I'm having issue formatting it to how I need to use it. The code was initially only for **Columns A** and **B**, but I need it to work for **Columns A:F**, I fixed the top portion to refer to my Columns of **A:F** but I'm having issues with the Array, I'm new to VBA so I'm not 100% sure on how that even works, I just know I'm getting an error on that line. Here's my code.

```
Sub DeleteRows()    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MC RRRs")
        Set Rng = Range("A:F").End(xlDown)
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    End With   
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?  Have you tried recording a macro and comparing the code it generates to this code?

Comment: `Columns := Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

Comment: That didn't work. I'm getting a run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: I posted an answer for you anyway that you might pick up a few ideas for how to make the macro you recorded more dynamic and adaptable.  :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question, your problem is with this line:

```
Set Rng = Range("A:F").End(xlDown)
```

*End method/property* should not be used since it will make you work on the last cell in `Range("A:F")`.
That means you only have one(1) cell to work on but your next line:

```
Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
```

tries to remove duplicates in two(2) columns (or at least 2 cells).
Also if only one(1) cell is selected, setting *Header* argument to `xlYes` will also generate error.
Also, since you are using *With Clause*, precede `Range` by a dot.
Something like:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim Rng As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MC RRRs")
        Set Rng = .Range("A:F")
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Columns("A:F").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:F").RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

I used the recorder button and it worked. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Good job for figuring it out. But I posted something that explains why your first code didn't work. Also [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) to help you improve coding.

Comment: Excellent link. I'm going to refer to that every few hours, I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1):

After plenty of toiling over this array issue, I finally produced some working code as well.  I hope this helps someone in need. The "-5" can be adjusted to suit your needs.  I didn't need to look at each column in my specific instance, but if you do, you can increase this to "-1".  One key to success was the parentheses around "arrColstoCheck" when using the RemoveDuplicates command.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim rngDupes As Range
Dim lngCols As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim strCols As String
Dim arrColstoCheck() As Variant
Dim wsComData1 as Worksheet

Set wsComData1 = Application.ActiveSheet

With wsComData1

    .Activate

    'Determine number of columns and rows in worksheet
    lngCols = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lngRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim arrColstoCheck(0 To lngCols - 5)
        'Fill array with column numbers
        For i = 0 To lngCols - 5
            arrColstoCheck(i) = i + 1
        Next i

    'Convert lngCols to Character for later use
    strCols = Chr(lngCols + 64)
    Set rngDupes = .Range("A1:" & strCols & lngRows)

        rngDupes.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(arrColstoCheck), Header:=xlNo

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested:   This will go through all the columns though.  If you want to set the limit, just insert a max instead of all columns.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim tempLast As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim colLet As String
Dim iCol As Integer  'because ConvertToLetter uses Integers

lastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = 0

'Get the true last row no matter what column it is in.  Loop through each and check.
For iCol = 1 To lastCol
    colLet = ConvertToLetter(iCol)
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(colLet & "2").End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range(colLet & "1:" & colLet & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
Next iCol

End Sub

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
'FROM http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833402
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```